# Does websocket payload needs to be compressed?

Tags: websocket, compression, blob

I deliver a large blob of about 50MB via websocket to the client.

If i manually gzip the payload before transmission, it goes down to about 10MB.

However, the question is, do i need to manually gzip the data, or does the websocket protocol already compress something?

I don't know where to see, how many MB are transfered over websocket (in Firefox).